# Anonymous functions referencing local variables in python

Tags: python, variables, callback, scope

How can I define anonymous functions in python, where the bahaviour should depend on the value of a local variable at definiton-time, and also accept arguments

Example:

```
def callback(val1, val2):
   print "{0} {1}".format(val1, val2)

i = 0
f0 = lambda x: callback(i, x)
i = 1
f1 = lambda x: callback(i, x)

f0(8) # prints "1, 8: but I'd like "0, 8" (value of 'i' when f0 was defined)
f1(8) # prints "1, 8"
```

Is something like this possible without wrapping my callback in its own a class?

Comment: you're defining the same lambda function twice.

Comment: @JoelCornett: Yes he is, but its his admitted non-working attempt to do a closure since he is always referring to that global `i`

Comment: @jdi: ah, I see. Yeah, I would go +1 for your answer with `partial`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Closures in python using [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

```
from functools import partial

i = 0
f0 = partial(callback, i)
i = 1
f1 = partial(callback, i)

f0()
# 0
f1()
# 1
```

`partial` is like a lambda but wraps the value at that moment into the arg. Not evaluating it when its called.

#### Wrapping only some of the args

Yes partial will allow you to wrap any number of the arguments, and the remaining args and kwargs can then be passed to the resulting partial object so that it acts like it was calling the original wrapped function...

```
def callback(val1, val2):
   print "{0} {1}".format(val1, val2)

i = 0
x = 8
f0 = partial(callback, i)
f0(x)
# 0 8
```

Essentially you have wrapped `callback(val1, val2)` into `callback(val2)` with `val1` being included as a closure already.

#### Example of similar effect using lambda

In case you really want to see how to do this with a lambda closure, you can see why it gets ugly and partial is preferred...

```
f0 = (lambda val1: lambda val2: callback(val1, val2))(i)
```

You have to wrap the scope variable into an outer function scope, and then reference that scope in the inner lambda function. Yuk.

#### Tracebacks from exceptions: partial vs lambda vs nested functions

With the influx of other answers, I thought I would outline one more reason to use partial as opposed to lambda, or a inner/outer function closure. Keep in mind I mean a function closure. functools.partial fixes the traceback you will get when your wrapped function raises an exception...

Consider this version that will raise a division by zero:

```
def callback(val1, val2):
    return val1 / val2
```

*Normal outter/inner closure*

```
def wrapper(fn, val1):
    def wrapped(val2):
            return fn(val1, val2)
    return wrapped

f0 = wrapper(callback, i)
f0(0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in wrapped
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in callback
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

*lambda closure*

```
f0 = (lambda val1: lambda val2: callback(val1, val2))(i)
f0(0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in callback
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

*And now for functools.partial*

```
f0 = partial(callback, i)
f0(0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in callback
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: Is it possible for `partial` to produce a function that accepts arguments? (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by functools.partial:

```
f0 = partial(callback, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that creates a function.  `partial` is another option, as mentioned by others.

```
def repeater(s):
  def anon():
      print s
  return anon

greet = repeater("Hello, World")
greet()
```

Answer (score 0):

While using functools.partial is the better solution in this case, you could also create explicit closures:

```
def callback_generator(val):
    def callback():
        return val
    return callback
i = 0
f0 = callback1(i)
i = 1
f1 = callback1(i)
```

This can also be done with lambdas, as shown in the comments below.

Comment: lambda IS the python anonymous function. And you can do multiple anonymous functions: `f = lambda x: (lambda y: y+1)(x+1)`. The way to do a closure with python and lambda would be:   `f = (lambda x: lambda: x)(i)`

Comment: See my answer for an update explaining how to do it completely with anonymous lambda functions.

Comment: Huh, I've never thought of nesting lambdas. Why the downvote though? Would you have gone into more detail if I hadn't brought up closures? Certainly that does make this answer useful.

Comment: It was because you had false information in your answer. But you fixed it. So its all good now.